# Split a value in json file

Tags: python, json, split

I have a problem to split a key in a json file:

For example I have this:

```json
"Geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [2.228328313996228, 48.946678205396019]}
```

And I want to split "coordinates" in 2 key, 1 for lat and the other for lon.

I want to have something like this:

```json
"lat": 2.228328313996228, "lon": 48.946678205396019
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: You don't need to "split" anything. After you parse the JSON, it's just a list in a dictionary, you can access each part with an index.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. Please read [ask]. If you're looking for help doing this, we'd want to know what you've already tried and what you need help with. For example, if you know how to parse JSON, then that part is irrelevant: just show us the Python data. You can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Comment: BTW, "latitude" is abbreviated "lat", not "late", and "longitude" is normally "lon" in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to read the contents of you json file into a dictionary. You didn't give any file name, so I am goint to invent one:

```
import json

with open("example.json", "r") as file:
    contents = json.load(file)

print(contents)
# {'Geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [2.228328313996228, 48.94667820539602]}}
```

Then you can write a fucntion, that splits coordinates into a dictionary and iterate through `contents` and apply the function:

```
def split_coordinates(geometry, coord_field_name="coordinates"):
    geometry[coord_field_name] = {
        "lat": geometry[coord_field_name][0],
        "lon": geometry[coord_field_name][1]
    }
    return geometry

print({key: split_coordinates(value) for key, value in contents.items()})
```

Output:

```
{
    'Geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': {
            'lat': 2.228328313996228,
            'lon': 48.94667820539602
        }
    }
}
```

If you then need to save the results into new file:

```
with open("output_example.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(contents, file)
```